# $3x + 2 > 8$ solved not using order of operation?

Tags: inequality

So im basically relearning algebra, using a site to teach myself the basics. I read about bodmas then shortly after about inequalities. In the practice questions i got a bunch of questions where the solution doesnt seem to use the order of operation, one being...

$$3x + 2 > 8$$

They first $-2$ from the $2$ then from the $8$. Then they divide the $3x$ by $3$ and the $8$ by $3$.

This confuses me because wouldn't you have to divide $\frac{3x}3$ then the same with the $8$ Before subtracting $2$ from the $2$ Then $8$? I don't know if im have a brain fart and missing a simple reason or maybe because its an inequality and nothing equals anything. Don't know.

So what i gather is that order of operations only really applies if there is an = sign in the equation? And that i could have divided by 3 but would have had to also divide the 2 by 3 along with the 8? which then leaves me with fractions and that just makes getting the solution a bit more complicated?

Comment: Make sure you understand why $\dfrac{3x+2}3\ne\dfrac{x+2}1$!! It's because $\dfrac{3x+2}3=(3x+2)\times\dfrac13$, which means you have to use the distributive property to get $\dfrac{3x}3+\dfrac23=x+\dfrac23$.

Comment: Order of operation is _implicit_ here - not in the solution of the equation but in the equation itself. In algebra when we write '$3x+2$' we _always_ mean $(3\cdot x)+2$ and not $3\cdot(x+2)$; multiplication is always given tighter 'precedence' than addition.

Comment: The question displays a fundamental misunderstanding of what the BODMAS order of operations means ... and that is what makes this a _good question._ One of the most valuable things in learning (and teaching) math, in my opinion, is to identify and dispel misunderstandings that hinder someone from doing mathematics.

Answer (score 5):

1. They probably divide the $6$ by $3$, since $6$ is what remains on the right side.
2. You can first divide by $3$, of course, but you must always divide **the whole equation**, not only a number, so dividing by $3$ would give

$$\frac{3x+2}{3}>\frac83$$

which can be simplified into $$\frac{3x}{3} + \frac23 > \frac83$$

and further to $$x + \frac23 > \frac83$$

Then, instead of subtracting $2$ from each side, you can subtract $\frac23$ to get
$$x + \frac23 - \frac23 > \frac83 - \frac23\\
x + 0 > \frac{8-2}3\\
x > \frac63\\
x>2$$

Comment: Can the downvoter please explain why this answer derserves a downvote?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. His question is: why can we subtract first and then divide, given division comes first in order of operations.

Comment: @avid19 And my answer explains that you can also divide first, and then subtract. I believe I answer the question in the second line of my question. I then clarify my answer.

Comment: Your answer doesn't address the source of confusion. Namely that order of operations only matters when EVALUATING expressions. Any answer that doesn't address this is unhelpful.

Comment: @avid19 Then we disagree. We will have to wait for input from the OP to see if he finds this answer helpful. In the mean time, I suggest you post your own answer if you feel this one is not good.

Comment: I think pjs36 answer is quite sufficient.

Comment: Yes this answer did help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The order of operations only comes into play when you're *evaluating* an expression: If you had to evaluate $3x + 2$ at $x = 2$, that is, simplify $3\cdot (2) + 2$, you would need the order of operations.

But when it comes to manipulating equations and inequalities, you don't need to do anything in any particular order (although some choices are easier than others, as the other answers have pointed out: subtraction first means you can avoid fractions).

As long as you use valid algebra at each step (whether you subtract or divide first), you'll get the same solution.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that $3x+2 \gt 8 \iff x \gt 2$ (though you have since edited out the conclusion).

If you divided by $3$ first you would get $x+\frac23 \gt \frac83$ reaching the same conclusion.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question is why can we subtract first and then divide given division comes before subtraction in order of operations.

Comment: @avid19 It answered the question as I originally saw it pre-edit, where the subtraction and then division were shown getting to the  correct answer but the partial division and then subtraction was not.